# Extracting Data from website page 1

Tags: python

Please, I want to extract the previous closing price, opening price, high, low and close from the picture below.

[The screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqASG.png)

Below is my python code but the output is skipping the needed to extract. The output it display is,

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url="http://www.nse.com.ng/market-data/trading-statistics/equities"
rawhtml = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
parsedhtml = bs(rawhtml, 'html.parser')

stock = parsedhtml.find('tbody', attrs={'id': 'datacontainer'})
print(stock)
```

I have been able to scrap the dynamic content. However, it returns only the content on the first page. The other contents are paginated and they have the same url. The url is [http://www.nse.com.ng/market-data/trading-statistics/equities]. My new code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import sys  
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication  
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl  
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage 

class Client (QWebEnginePage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
    self.html = ''
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_Finished)  
    self.load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _on_load_Finished(self, result):  
    self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
    print('Load Finished')

  def Callable (self, html_str):
      self.html = html_str
      self.app.quit()
  #  self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://www.nse.com.ng/market-data/trading-statistics/equities'  
r = Client(url)  
#parsedhtml = r.mainFrame.toHtml() 
soup = bs(r.html, 'html.parser')
stock = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table table-condensed table-striped'})
print(stock)
```

'

Please, any idea on how to unwrap the other paginated items

Thanks.

@Shivam Pandya

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Null output because when you're requesting that page, there is no table data. The value there are getting fetched dynamically, so those values will get rendered when you load the web page.

To get the idea of what I am telling, try printing your "parsedhtml" variable and then observe the output you get with the photo you have attached with the question.

Comment: Thanks Shivam for your response. I understand your point. The output of my "parsedhtml" did not contain those values which means they are being rendered dynamically. Please, is their any other means i can scrap those values? Thank you.

Comment: I have been able to scrap the dynamic content. However, it returns only the content on the first page. The other contents are paginated and they have the same url.